# NoClassDefFoundError error in ant run command

Tags: ant

I have created a basic selenium project which I am  trying to run with testNG using ant. 
I am getting this below error while running ant run . Upto  compile, build is ok.

some of the solutions I have found from Internet is adding Jcommander.jar in my classpath but it is already added in my classpath. Here is the error that I am getting in CMD

```
run:
[testng] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
[testng]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[testng]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
[testng]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
[testng]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
testng]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
[testng]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)                    
testng]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
[testng] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:            com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
[testng]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[testng]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[testng]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[testng]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[testng]     ... 7 more
[testng] Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and    try again
testng] The tests failed.
```

here is my classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar     files/selenium-2.53.0/selenium-java-2.53.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/bsh-2.0b4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/gson-2.3.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/guava-19.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/httpmime-4.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/jcommander-1.48.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/jna-4.1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/junit-4.12.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs/testng-6.9.9.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: What does the Ant script look like? In particular, what does the `<testng>` in the Ant script look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have listed the file that Eclipse uses to manage its classpath, but this file is not used by ANT.

ANT is a separate tool and has a "build.xml" that details its build logic. To manage your ANT classpath I would recommend the following construct:

```
<property name="lib.dir" location="C:/Users/ASOKE/Desktop/Selenium All Docs/Jar files/selenium-2.53.0/libs"/>

<path id="compile.path">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Which can be used to compile jars as follows:

```
<target name="compile" description="Compile code">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}/classes" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" classpathref="compile.path"/>
</target>
```

Hopefully this gives you a flavour for how ANT works.

In conclusion don't forget that Eclipse is a developer tool and has it's own mechanism for building Java. The reason people use alternate build tools like ANT, Maven and Gradle is because production builds normally happen on dedicated build servers in absence of GUI tooling.

**PS**

- If you'd like ANT and Eclipse to share their jars then I'd recommend using a dependency management tool like [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), which has an [Eclipse plugin](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/).